# how does state gets pulled in sagas.js when using redux saga with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I am reading a codebase which involves redux-saga .I just started with redux-saga and I see that there are numerous instances in saga.js whee state has been pulled out.

```
function* fetchxyz({ Id }) {
  try {
    const authToken = yield select(state => state.auth.authToken);
    const data = yield call(
      getxyz1,
      authToken,
      Id
    );
    yield put({
      type: FETCH_XYZ_SUCCESS,
      response:data
    });


}
```

I am bit puzzled as how this state got pulled in this saga.js .I strongly feel that I lack some understanding somewhere as I don't get that how state got pulled out in saga.js .

Comment: so you are asking how [`select`](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/) works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redux-saga is a redux middleware. Every redux middleware has access to redux state through the getState function.

Redux docs: https://redux.js.org/api/applymiddleware#arguments

Redux-saga usage: https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/packages/core/src/internal/middleware.js#L13

Sagas are generators over which the redux-saga library iterates and then deals with the individual yielded effects. To access state in redux saga you use the `select` effect like in your example.

So all that redux-saga does is it calls the provided selector function with a return value of the `getState` function as its parameter.

https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/packages/core/src/internal/effectRunnerMap.js#L282

The yielded expression can be evaluated into the return value of the selector function by passing the return value as a parameter to the `next` function on the iterator. This is just normal generator behavior:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*#Passing_arguments_into_Generators